# Ajax post return empty object always to controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, post, model-view-controller

I'm trying to do a post using Ajax in my ASP.NET MVC app, but the object is always empty.

This is my controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Newinventary(InventaryAjax inventary)
{
    return Json(inventary);
}
```

This in my class InventaryAjax:

```
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal SupplierCode { get; set; }
    public string WithdrawalOrder { get; set; }
    public string EnterpriseDocument { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int LerRaee { get; set; }
    public string Weigth { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string GeneralComments { get; set; }
    public string HdserialsNumbers { get; set; }
```

This is my call:

```
$("body").on("click", "#btnAdd", function () {
        var inventary = new Object();
        inventary.SupplierCode = $("#txtSupplier").val();
        inventary.WithdrawalOrder = $("#txtOrden").val();
        inventary.EnterpriseDocument = $("#txtDocumento").val();
        inventary.LerRaee = $("#txtLER").val();
        inventary.Weigth = $("#txtPeso").val();
        inventary.Description = $("#txtDescripcion").val();
        inventary.SerialNumber = $("#txtSN").val();
        inventary.HdserialsNumbers = $("#txtSNHDD").val();
        inventary.Price = $("#txtPrecio").val();
        inventary.GeneralComments = $("#txtObservaciones").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Almacen/NewInventary",
            data: JSON.stringify(inventary),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                var row = $("#tblInventary tr:last-child");
                if ($("#tblInventary tr:last-child span").eq(0).html() != "&nbsp;") {
                    row = row.clone();
                }
                AppendRow(row, r.SupplierCode,
                    r.WithdrawalOrder, r.EnterpriseDocument,
                    r.LerRaee, r.Weigth, r.Description,
                    r.SerialNumber, r.HdserialsNumbers,
                    r.Price, r.GeneralComments);
                txtLER.val("");
                txtPeso.val("");
                txtDescripcion.val("");
                txtSN.val("");
                txtSNHDD.val("");
                txtPrecio.val("");
                txtObservaciones.val("");
            }
        });
    });
```

I checked the post call in the browser and the object is filled:

```
Description: "5"
EnterpriseDocument: "2"
GeneralComments: "9"
HdserialsNumbers: "7"
LerRaee: "3"
Price: "8"
SerialNumber: "6"
SupplierCode: "0"
Weigth: "4"
WithdrawalOrder: "1"
```

But when I check in the method the object received in the controller is all null

[UPDATE]
I tried changing the data of the ajax post:

```
 $("body").on("click", "#btnAdd", function () {
            var inventary = new Object();
            inventary.SupplierCode = $("#txtSupplier").val();
            inventary.WithdrawalOrder = $("#txtOrden").val();
            inventary.EnterpriseDocument = $("#txtDocumento").val();
            inventary.LerRaee = $("#txtLER").val();
            inventary.Weigth = $("#txtPeso").val();
            inventary.Description = $("#txtDescripcion").val();
            inventary.SerialNumber = $("#txtSN").val();
            inventary.HdserialsNumbers = $("#txtSNHDD").val();
            inventary.Price = $("#txtPrecio").val();
            inventary.GeneralComments = $("#txtObservaciones").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Almacen/NewInventary",
                data: {inventary : inventary },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    var row = $("#tblInventary tr:last-child");
                    if ($("#tblInventary tr:last-child span").eq(0).html() != "&nbsp;") {
                        row = row.clone();
                    }
                    AppendRow(row, r.SupplierCode,
                        r.WithdrawalOrder, r.EnterpriseDocument,
                        r.LerRaee, r.Weigth, r.Description,
                        r.SerialNumber, r.HdserialsNumbers,
                        r.Price, r.GeneralComments);
                    txtLER.val("");
                    txtPeso.val("");
                    txtDescripcion.val("");
                    txtSN.val("");
                    txtSNHDD.val("");
                    txtPrecio.val("");
                    txtObservaciones.val("");
                }
            });
        });
```

I check and the object is send in the post:

[image]

But the JsonResult still is receiving an empty inventaryAjax

[image]

[UPDATE 2]

I change the data sent to a json only and the data type received in the method of the controller

```
public ActionResult InsertInventary(string data)
{
    InventaryAjax inventary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InventaryAjax>(data);
    return Json(inventary);
}

$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("InsertInventary","Almacen")',
                data: JSON.stringify(inventary) ,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    var row = $("#tblInventary tr:last-child");
                    if ($("#tblInventary tr:last-child span").eq(0).html() != "&nbsp;") {
                        row = row.clone();
                    }
                    AppendRow(row, r.SupplierCode,
                        r.WithdrawalOrder, r.EnterpriseDocument,
                        r.LerRaee, r.Weigth, r.Description,
                        r.SerialNumber, r.HdserialsNumbers,
                        r.Price, r.GeneralComments);
                    txtLER.val("");
                    txtPeso.val("");
                    txtDescripcion.val("");
                    txtSN.val("");
                    txtSNHDD.val("");
                    txtPrecio.val("");
                    txtObservaciones.val("");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Did you try to send the object itself? `data: inventary`

Comment: Yes I tried but it seems does not work

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
 data: JSON.stringify(inventary),
```

TO

```
data: {inventary : inventary } ,
```

you don't need to stringify the object

I am using your code I am getting all the values

[image: See here]

Comment: O tried already and I see that the object is send: SupplierCode=1&WithdrawalOrder=2&EnterpriseDocument=3&LerRaee=4&Weigth=5&Description=6&SerialNumber=7&HdserialsNumbers=8&Price=9&GeneralComments=0. But I still receive empty in the JsonResult

Comment: @FranciscoGonzalez try updated answer see what you get

Comment: I dont know where the problem could be

Comment: @FranciscoGonzalez have you solved this issue? I just want to know which newtonsoft version you are using

Comment: No I cant fix the problem, I use the version 12.0.2

Answer (score 0):

This is what I recommend,

Still use the line below

```
 data: JSON.stringify(inventary)
```

but change your controller to use `JsonConvert` to deserialize the object

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Newinventary(string data)
{
    InventaryAjax inventary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InventaryAjax>(data);
    return Json(inventary);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Use this for posting

```
$.post("/Almacen/NewInventary",
    {
        data: JSON.stringify({
            data : inventory
        })
   },
   function (data, status) {
      console.log(data);
   });
```

also debug in your controller to be sure the value of `string` data is coming from the ajax.

Comment: I tried too, and I add a document write to see the post data to be send an it seems correct:
{"SupplierCode":"1","WithdrawalOrder":"2","EnterpriseDocument":"3","LerRaee":"4","Weigth":"5","Description":"6","SerialNumber":"7","HdserialsNumbers":"8","Price":"9","GeneralComments":"0"}
I dont know where the problem could be

Comment: I update my question with you solution but I dont see what could be happening